# Error Apache Tomcat after deploy

Tags: java, tomcat

I have application got from another computer and  try to deploy it in my tomcat. but I get error:

```js
HTTP Status 500 - Servlet execution threw an exception

type Exception report

message Servlet execution threw an exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception

root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class paris.GlobalParam
 paris.FormTemplate.<init>(FormTemplate.java:22)
 paris.loginHandler.Login.<init>(Login.java:27)
 sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 org.zkoss.zk.ui.metainfo.ComponentInfo.toComposer(ComponentInfo.java:399)
 org.zkoss.zk.ui.metainfo.ComponentInfo.toComposer(ComponentInfo.java:391)
 org.zkoss.zk.ui.metainfo.ComponentInfo.toComposers(ComponentInfo.java:359)
 org.zkoss.zk.ui.metainfo.ComponentInfo.resolveComposer(ComponentInfo.java:346)
 org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild0(UiEngineImpl.java:599)
 org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild(UiEngineImpl.java:593)
 org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate0(UiEngineImpl.java:537)
 org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild(UiEngineImpl.java:569)
 org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate0(UiEngineImpl.java:537)
 org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate(UiEngineImpl.java:504)
 org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execNewPage0(UiEngineImpl.java:365)
 org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execNewPage(UiEngineImpl.java:286)
 org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet.process(DHtmlLayoutServlet.java:237)
 org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet.doGet(DHtmlLayoutServlet.java:159)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
```

Please help what I should do with that error message..

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried searching for `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`? I can see a large quantity of questions regarding that error.

Answer (score 0):

Logs suggest either you don't have the right ZK jar in class-path or may be the ZK version is different in both machines?.

Comment: so does it mean I have to remove ZK thing in lib folder?

Comment: I dont think so - you need to see what are the differences between in old and new server. Starting with ZK version or location in path